# Wordpress "paginate_links" refers to “Not Found” page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to make a simple pagination nav menu in WordPress 3.4.2., using the following code:

```
global $wp_query;
                $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

                if($total_pages > 1) {

                    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                    echo paginate_links(array(
                        'base'  =>  get_pagenum_link(1).'%_%',
                        'format'    =>  'page/%#%',
                        'current'   =>  $current_page,
                        'total'     =>  $total_pages,
                        'prev_next' =>  false,
                        'type'      =>  'list'

                    ));
                }
```

But when I click on a page link it's reffering me to:

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /wptest/page/2 was not found on this server.**

I know that it's probably something simple that I missed but I don't know what is it. 
Is there a way of doing this kind of pagination *without external plugins or hacks*?

Tried changing the settings in 'Reading' and 'Permalinks' and still no go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error wasn't in Wordpress. I forgot to turn the *rewrite module* of WAMP.